# Dygraphs - black areas / artefacts appearing for some users

Tags: dygraphs, areas

Some users are experiencing black rectangles appearing in their dygraphs, which seem to be triggered by hover events.

Using FireFox 38.0.5 on windows 64 bit machine.

I have the latest version of dygraphs - v1.2

Has anyone else experienced this and know of a cure?

Only recently become apparent, and some users have been using their graphs since 2011, so my guess is this may be linked to a Windows update.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have a demo link?

Comment: Yes, here is one example. https://www.london-electronics.com/view_dygraph.php

Comment: Here is a black artefact which comes and gos as you mouse over the graph.  https://www.london-electronics.com/dygraph_artefact.png

Comment: This from the dygraphs.com site. Note the black bars in the horizontal axis. https://www.london-electronics.com/2015_06_12_14_11_36_2015_06_12_14_10_13_Dygraphs_Gallery.png_Paint.png